# Mongo unwind two arrays at once

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that can have multiple tags and multiple detected dates corresponding to the tags like so :

```
{
    "shop"=>"my_shop",
    "date"=>[
              [2015-01-03 00:00:00 UTC, 2015-01-10 00:00:00 UTC],
              [2015-01-10 00:00:00 UTC]
            ], 
    "tag"=>["test_tag1", "test_tag2"]
}
```

Each array in "date" corresponds to a tag, so just unwinding twice looses this match.

I would like to keep this match like so :

```
{
    "shop"=>"my_shop",
    "date"=>2015-01-03 00:00:00 UTC, 
    "tag"=>"test_tag1"
},
{
    "shop"=>"my_shop",
    "date"=>2015-01-10 00:00:00 UTC, 
    "tag"=>"test_tag1"
},
{
    "shop"=>"my_shop",
    "date"=>2015-01-10 00:00:00 UTC, 
    "tag"=>"test_tag2"
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do this. The design for your document is not correct. If you adjust your collection like below, you might get your desired result.

```
{
    "shop": "my_shop",
    "tags_with_date": [
        {
            "tag": "test_tag1",
            "date": [
                2015-01-0300: 00: 00UTC,
                2015-01-1000: 00: 00UTC
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "test_tag2",
            "date": [
                2015-01-1000: 00: 00UTC
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```